# PowerShell: Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2"

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

Trying to determine if AD accounts have been modified in the last 2 hours.

If I manually do a Get-ADUser and then compare `$ObjDelta = ((Get-Date) - ($i.Modified))` I can successfully check the "Hours" value.

> Days              : 0
> Hours             : 2
> Minutes           : 45
> Seconds           : 10
> Milliseconds      : 321
> Ticks             : 99103217697
> TotalDays         : 0.114702798260417
> TotalHours        : 2.75286715825
> TotalMinutes      : 165.172029495
> TotalSeconds      : 9910.3217697
> TotalMilliseconds : 9910321.7697

Yet when I put it in a script with

```
$Output = Foreach ($i in $Imported) {
    $ObjDelta = ((Get-Date) - ($i.Modified))
    If ($ObjDelta.Hours -gt "1") {
        <Do things here>
    }
```

I get a running error on each $i of

> Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - $ObjDelta = ((Get-Date) - ($i.Modified))
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

I have confirmed that the "Modified" value is populated on these accounts.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `$Imported`? Data imported from a CSV file?

Comment: Correct. $Imported is from a CSV file, which does contain "Modified" values.

Comment: ... in which format? Can you post a few sample lines from the CSV?

Answer (score 2):

The second argument can be [timespan] or [datetime]:

```
[datetime]::op_Subtraction

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static datetime op_Subtraction(datetime d, timespan t)
static timespan op_Subtraction(datetime d1, datetime d2)
```

```
(get-date) - [datetime]'12/3'


Days              : 1
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 24
Milliseconds      : 542
Ticks             : 864845423929
TotalDays         : 1.00097849991782
TotalHours        : 24.0234839980278
TotalMinutes      : 1441.40903988167
TotalSeconds      : 86484.5423929
TotalMilliseconds : 86484542.3929
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 - ended up having to use `[DateTime]::Parse($i.Modified))`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

As you've discovered yourself, you need to convert `$i.Modified` to a `[datetime]` instance explicitly, using the rules of the *current* culture, given that the data came from a CSV presumably created with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```bash
$ObjDelta = (Get-Date) - (Get-Date $i.Modified) # or: [datetime]::Parse($i.Modified)
```

Note:

- The above assumes that the CSV data was created while the *same* culture as your current one was in effect. If not, see the next section for a solution.
- Only if your current culture *happens to be* `en-US` (US-English) would
  `[datetime] $i.Modified`, i.e. a simple *cast* be sufficient, for the reasons explained in the next section.

---

##### Background information:

As [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597287/45375) explains, a subtraction operation (`-`) with a [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances as the LHS requires as its RHS either another `[datetime]` instance or a [`[timespan]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instance. In the former case the result is a *time span* (i.e. a `[timespan]` instance), in the latter a *new point in time* (i.e. a different `[datetime]` instance).

The reason that `(Get-Date) - $i.Modified` didn't work in your case is that you loaded your data *from a CSV file*, presumably with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), and CSV data is *inherently untyped*, or, more accurately, invariably `[string]`-typed.

While PowerShell generally attempts *automatic conversions* to suitable operand types, it cannot do so in the case at hand, because it is possible to convert a string to *either* of the two supported RHS types, which results in the error message complaining about ambiguous overloads you saw.<sup>[1]</sup>

PowerShell supports convenient from-*string* conversions simply using a *cast* to the target type (placing a *type literal* such as `[datetime]` before the value to convert), which translate into calls to the static `::Parse()` method behind the scenes (if exposed by the target type).

For instance, `[datetime] '1970/01/01'` is translated to
`[datetime]::Parse('1970/01/01', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`

Note the use of `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`: PowerShell by design, if available, requests use of this - as the name suggests - *invariant* culture, which is based on, but distinct from, the US-English culture.

By contrast:

- Passing *only* a string to [`[dateteime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse) uses the *current culture*'s formats; e.g., `[datetime]::Parse('6.12')` is interpreted as 12 June (month-first with culture `en-US` (US-English) in effect, and as 6 December (day-first) in a culture such as `fr-FR` (French).

  - The **solution above therefore only works if the CSV data was created *with the same (or at least a compatible) culture in effect* as the one in effect when the data is read**.  If this assumption doesn't hold, you'll have to parse the date/time strings with an explicit format string that matches the data, using [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact); e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Parse as day.month.year
    [datetime]::ParseExact('6.12.2023', 'd\.M\.yyyy', $null)
    ```
- Curiously - and regrettably - when passing strings as *arguments* to *binary cmdlets* (as opposed to cmdlet-like scripts and functions written *in PowerShell*), it is also the *current* culture that is used, so that `Get-Date 6.12` exhibits the same culture-dependent behavior as `[datetime]::Parse('6.12')`.

  - This is a known inconsistency that *will not be fixed*, however, so as to preserve backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989).
  - In the code at the top, this behavior is taken advantage of; however, you may prefer use of `[datetime]::Parse($i.Modified)` to avoid ambiguity.

The reason that ***culture-sensitive* parsing of `$i.Modified` is necessary** in your case (`Get-Date $i.Modified` or `[datetime]::Parse($i.Modified)`) is the **- unfortunate - behavior of [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)** (and its in-memory counterpart, **[`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)**) to  ***invariably* use the *current culture*** when stringifying dates (`[datetime]`) and (fractional) numbers (typically, `[double]`):

- This hampers the portability of CSV data generated this way.

  - Note what while there is a **`-UseCulture`** switch, **the only culture-sensitive aspect it controls is the *separator character***: *by default*, it is *always* `,` (i.e., culture-*insensitive*, ironically); *with `-UseCulture`* it is the *current culture*'s list separator, such as `;` in the French culture.
  - [GitHub issue #20383](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20383#issuecomment-1743056797), in the context of discussing improvements to the stringification of complex objects, summarizes the culture-related problems of the CSV cmdlets; ideally, *by default* they would be culture-invariance *consistently and comprehensively*, with (consistent and comprehensive) culture-sensitivity only coming into play *on demand*, with `-UseCulture`; sadly, this is again not an option if backward compatibility must be maintained.
- The **only way to avoid culture-sensitivity is to generate string representations of the property (column) values *explicitly***, in the simplest case via using a `[string]` cast, which stringifies *with the invariant culture*; e.g.:

  ```bash
  [pscustomobject] @{ PropA = 'string'; PropB = Get-Date; PropC = 1.5 } |
    ForEach-Object {
      $oht = [ordered] @{} # helper hashtable for constructing an all-strings clone of the object
      foreach ($p in $_.psobject.Properties) {
        # Use PowerShell's [string] cast, which uses *culture-invariant* stringification
        $oht[$p.Name] = [string] $p.Value
      }
      # Construct and output the all-strings clone.
      [pscustomobject] $oht
    } |
    ConvertTo-Csv
  ```

  - The above yields *culture-invariant* CSV data; e.g.:

    ```bash
    "PropA","PropB","PropC"
    "string","12/06/2023 15:04:02","1.5"
    ```
  - When such culture-invariant data is parsed, *regular PowerShell casts* can then be used for from-string conversion (e.g. `[datetime] $i.Modified` or `[double] $i.Ratio`)

---

<sup>[1] Note that during overload resolution (for the call to the `op_Subtraction()` method call underlying the operator in this case), PowerShell generally only consults the *type* of the arguments, not also their *content*.</sup>